# How to handle databasechangelog table after copying $JENKINS_HOME/jobs from one Jenkins to another?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, liquibase

I need guidance to migrate Liquibase from one Jenkins to another.  I understand I can copy $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job_name> to copy the configs and build history.  I am not clear what I need to do next. I would like to ensure that I can rollback old builds.

1. Should I copy DATABASECHANGELOG rows by <job_name>?
2. Should I issue changelog-sync-to-tag to create a bookmark as a fresh start?
   a. migration-changelog.xml
   `<changeSet id="1.0" author="liquibase"> <tagDatabase tag="Post-Migration"/> </changeSet>`
   b.
   liquibase changelog-sync-to-tag --tag=Post-Migration --changelog-file=migration-changelog.xml

Thanks,
Elly

I am looking for suggestions/answers